# Android : fragment is not replaced

Tags: java, android, android-fragments

What I want to do is that when I click a button ( BtnA or BtnB) , the fragment just below buttons is replaced by corresponding fragment (FragmentA or FragmentB).

this is my code in MainActivity.java

```
@Override
public void onClick(View v) {
    Fragment replacableFragment = new Fragment();
    switch (v.getId()){
        case R.id.button1:
        {
            replacableFragment = new Fragment_One();
            Log.d("OnClick","button1");
            break;
        }
        case R.id.button2:
        {
            replacableFragment = new Fragment_Two();
            Log.d("OnClick","button2");
            break;
        }
    }
    FragmentManager manager=  getFragmentManager();
    Log.d("OnClick","1");
    FragmentTransaction transaction = manager.beginTransaction();

    Log.d("OnClick","2");
    transaction.add(R.id.fragmentPlace, replacableFragment);
    //transaction.addToBackStack(null);
    Log.d("OnClick","3");
    transaction.commit();
}
```

and this is my code of Fragment_One.java

```
public class Fragment_One extends Fragment{
@Override
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    return inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_one,container,false);
    }
}
```

Fragment_Two.java is the same with 'inflater.inflater(R.layout.fragment_two,container,false);'

When I click any button, logcat shows everything exactly. But Fragment is not replaced at all.
I think my code has no problem to function it.

Can anyone know about this?

xml files for my project are below:

activity_main.xml

```
<TextView android:text="@string/hello_world" android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content" />
<Button
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:text="FRAGMENT ONE"
    android:id="@+id/button1"/>
<Button
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:text="FRAGMENT TWO"
    android:id="@+id/button2"/>
<fragment
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:id="@+id/fragmentPlace"
    android:name="lkm.com.practical5_3.Fragment_One"/>
```

fragment_one.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
    <LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent" android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:background="@android:color/holo_orange_dark"
    android:orientation="vertical">
    <TextView
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:text="THIS IS FRAGMENT ONE"
        android:id="@+id/text1"/>
</LinearLayout>
```

fragment_two.xml

The same one as 'fragment_one.xml'

Answer (score 0):

use this

```
transaction.replace(R.id.fragmentPlace, replacableFragment).commit();
```

Comment: Thank you for answering, but it doesn't work and I could expect it because that doesn't mean and change anything...

Comment: I think you should use a layout for fragment container insted of fragment.

Comment: Is there something called 'Fragment Container'? I don't think so... isn't it? I don't understand what you mean

Comment: ya.     add(int containerViewId, Fragment fragment)  this is the syntax i found from developer site for transaction.replace/add .fragment container id is the id of the view that holds fragment layout

Comment: Oh, I tried this before but it does have no effect either like method 'replace'

Answer (score 0):

I want to anser my question!

The problem was the container!

At activiy_main.xml, the container of the fragment ais defined as 'fragment ~/'.

I fix it as 'FrameLayout ~/' and it was succesfful!

Thank you!